# Symfony2: Can't load \Elastica_Query_Text() class

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to load class in my controller `Elastica_Query_Text();`

```
public function indexAction(Request $request, $page = 1)
{
    $query = $request->attributes->get('query');
    $finder = $this->get('fos_elastica.finder.app.entries');
    $nameQuery = new \Elastica_Query_Text();
```

And I am getting this error message:

> Attempted to load class "Elastica_Query_Text" from the global
>   namespace. Did you forget a "use" statement?

My use statements are as follow:

```
use AppBundle\Entity\Entries;
use AppBundle\Form\EntriesType;
use Elastica\Index;
use Elastica\Query;
use Elastica\Query\Term;
use Pagerfanta\Adapter\ElasticaAdapter;
```

What am I missing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem add to you use statements following:

```
use FOQ\ElasticaBundle\Repository;
```